# How to change button background color based on database boolean field in ASP.NET using VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to change the button's background color based on the "Status" field in my database. Where `False = Green` and `True = Red`.

I'm using ASP.NET but I don't know how to do it, because I can only access the database from the '.aspx.vb' files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background color of Buttons like this.

```
If (Convert.ToBoolean(reader("status")) = true) Then
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
Else
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Green
End If
```

This snippet's usage is based on looping the Database values with a [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).